# Find the most frequent date for every group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm querying the austin crime dataset from BigQuery.

This is the preview:

[image]

I want to query the total incidences and the most frequent day they happened, grouped by crime type.

My actual query goes like this:

```
SELECT description, count(*) as incidences 
FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime
group by description
order by incidences desc;
```

But i don´t find a way to find the day with most cases for every type of crime

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output, also define what " the most frequent day" is.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One method is to aggregate by the `description` and `weekday`.  Use window functions to determine the total over the `description` and the highest weekday total:

```
select description, weekday, weekday_incidences, incidences
from (select description, format_timestamp('%a', timestamp) as weekday,
             ​count(*) as weekday_incidences,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by description) as incidences,
             row_number() over (partition by description order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime` c
      group by description, weekday
     ) c
where seqnum = 1
order by incidences desc;
```